# Can <NAV> contain mixed content?

Tags: html

According to HTML spec, the `<nav>` tag defines a set of navigation links.

I want to build a quite complex "menu", so my `<nav>` would contain set of `<div>`s, and each of them would contain `<img>`, description in `<p>` and the actual link in `<h2>`.

```
<nav>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="screenshot1.png" alt="">
    <p>Description of website 1</p>
    <h2><a href="#">Website 1</a></h2>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
    <img src="screenshot2.png" alt="">
    <p>Description of website 2</p>
    <h2><a href="#">Website 2</a></h2>
 </div>
</nav>
```

The question is: **is that semantically correct?**

Comment: Sure, that's fine. The contents of your `<nav>` are intended for navigation.

Comment: It's perfectly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to HTML spec, the `<nav>` tag defines a set of navigation
>   links.

No it doesn't, [the specification states](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element)

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other
>   pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.
>
> ...
>
> A nav element doesn't have to contain a list, it can contain other
>   kinds of content as well. In this navigation block, links are provided
>   in prose:
>
> ```
> <nav>
>  <h1>Navigation</h1>
>  <p>You are on my home page. To the north lies <a href="/blog">my
>  blog</a>, from whence the sounds of battle can be heard. To the east
>  you can see a large mountain, upon which many <a
>  href="/school">school papers</a> are littered. Far up thus mountain
>  you can spy a little figure who appears to be me, desperately
>  scribbling a <a href="/school/thesis">thesis</a>.</p>
>  <p>To the west are several exits. One fun-looking exit is labeled <a
>  href="http://games.example.com/">"games"</a>. Another more
>  boring-looking exit is labeled <a
>  href="http://isp.example.net/">ISP™</a>.</p>
>  <p>To the south lies a dark and dank <a href="/about">contacts
>  page</a>. Cobwebs cover its disused entrance, and at one point you
>  see a rat run quickly out of the page.</p>
> </nav>
> ```

So the specification very explicitly states that a `<nav>` tag can contain mixed content without an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct.

You can confirm it yourself by inspecting the elements in browser's Dev tools. If it were incorrect the browser would move out the invalid elements. See the second snippet below to see what happens to incorrect HTML.

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="screenshot1.png" alt="">
    <p>Description of website 1</p>
    <h2><a href="#">Website 1</a></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="screenshot2.png" alt="">
    <p>Description of website 2</p>
    <h2><a href="#">Website 2</a></h2>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### Incorrect HTML

```html
<table>
  <div>
    Incorrectly placed div
  </div>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Correct TD.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```